# Edit first item of dynamic rows in ssrs?

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, rows, row-number

My ssrs has three row groups nested, and in one of the rows the report runs many times.

I'd like to add something simple to the rows, such as "%" at the end, but only on the first row returned, not the rest of the dynamic rows. My idea was to use:
=RowNumber("detailsGroup") but all that returns is one for each row. Is there another SSRS method?

I was also thinking of using the "is" operator and comparing the dynamic values to the First operator, but running the report gave #ERROR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using groups you should be able to use Previous() function.

EXample:

`Group 1 - ClientName
Group 2 - Region
Group 3 - SubRegion
Detail - data for above 3 groups`

If I just want to add something in one of the detail data then I would use ..

```
=Fields!CallReason.Value + IIF(Previous(Fields!ClientName.Value) <> Fields!ClientName.Value , " Add Text For First Line", "")
```